# How to debug "OSError: -9" saving a tiff via libtiff and pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a TIFF file that I cannot manipulate with pillow. I know pillow is a user of libtiff, but the error messages are insufficient to be able to debug the issue:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(open("input.tif", "rb"))
image.save("out.tiff")
```

I instantly get the following (truncated) traceback:

```
PIL/Image.py in _ensure_mutable(self)
    616     def _ensure_mutable(self):
    617         if self.readonly:
--> 618             self._copy()
    619         else:
    620             self.load()

PIL/Image.py in _copy(self)
    609 
    610     def _copy(self):
--> 611         self.load()
    612         self.im = self.im.copy()
    613         self.pyaccess = None

PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py in load(self)
   1055     def load(self):
   1056         if self.tile and self.use_load_libtiff:
-> 1057             return self._load_libtiff()
   1058         return super().load()
   1059 

PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py in _load_libtiff(self)
   1159 
   1160         if err < 0:
-> 1161             raise OSError(err)
   1162 
   1163         return Image.Image.load(self)

OSError: -9
```

is there a way to enable more useful debugging information so I have some idea where the failure occurred? To be clear, the error is happening on the call to `image.save`. Image.save does the following to manipulate the file, using libtiff:

```
decoder = Image._getdecoder(
            self.mode, "libtiff", tuple(args), self.decoderconfig
        )
...
...
decoder.decode(...)
```

Comment: `raise OSError(err)` on the last step leads to `OSError: -1`. You could take a look at the source code for `_load_libtiff(self)` in PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py and check what conditions lead to `err = -9`. Is the error occurring during `PIL.Image.open` or `image.save`? If it is `open`, you could try using `Image.open("input.tif")` directly instead of using Python's `open` function first. If it is `save`, are you sure you have permissions to write to that directory. Also are you sure the file does contain just one image? Tiff files can contain multiple "pages".

Comment: @NiklasMertsch - the error happens on the call to `save` - I updated the question to make that more clear. My apologies. The file does contain multiple pages. The code in question "works" with some multi-page tiff files and not with others. I'm not sure if its TAG related, compression related, etc.

Comment: Hmm. `err` can be returned by one of three different lines. If it's reproducible enough to set a breakpoint earlier in the function, it might be interesting to step through (and _into_ that individual function; even if it calls to a C function, that lets you check that C function's docs).

Comment: I cannot help you with tiff-related problems, maybe a debugger helps, like Charles suggested. Can you save the image as other formats (e.g. png)?

Comment: Maybe you can share the TIFF so other folks can try?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't it's a fax with sensitive information in it. Any edit I attempt (to redact it so I can share it) "fixes" whatever issues there is to begin with